# Device is lagging on Notification and Recent Apps because of my application

Tags: android

Don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but I noticed that when I have my application in the Recent Apps, the Recent Apps becomes very laggy until I remove it in there. This also applies to when I receive notification from my app, swiping down the notifications is very slow until I dismiss the notifs for my app.

Anyone experienced something like this? I'm not sure what to look for and I don't know what might have caused this. Any insight will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this issue drives me crazy for more than a year. It seems to be related to the framework. Samsungs touchwiz ends in a lagging system UI, a Google nexus 6p does the job as expected and a Google pixel does not get any lags, but on this device the notification will freeze after some days. No error, no warning, 100% annoying.

Comment: Try to reduce the file size of the resources.. You may want to compress the image to get a better performance. But in my situation it doesn't have helped.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours and hours with trial and error I am pretty sure to get it fixed. The solution looks very weird, but as I said, for me it did the trick.

Please try this:

1. Create a utility class (Utils.java), and nest this method inside:

   ```
   public static void runOnBackgroundThread(final Callable callable) {
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               callable.call();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   };
   new Thread(runnable).start();
   ```

   }
2. Modify your notification class processing the update on the background.

Pseudo code:

```
public void update(final long totalRx, final long totalTx) {
    Utils.runOnBackgroundThread(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {

            // do your calculations and/or content changes

            mNotificationManager.notify(Const.NOTIFICATION_NETWORK, mBuilder.build());

            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.